# Unable to modify MACRO & Variables color

Tags: visual-studio-code

How to modify MACRO color?

And how to modify variable color? the following settings doesn't work. Vars are always white.

Working on C lang mostly. Any suggestions are appreciated..

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "variables": "#2b3590",
    "textMateRules": [
    {
        "name": "Function argument",
        "scope": "variable.parameter",
        "settings": {
            "fontStyle": "",
            "foreground": "#6089B4"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Function Call Variable",
        "scope": "variable.other.property",
        "settings": {
            "fontStyle": "",
            "foreground": "#9872A2"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Class Variable",
        "scope": "variable.other, variable.js, punctuation.separator.variable",
        "settings": {
            "fontStyle": "",
            "foreground": "#6089B4"
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Normal Variable",
        "scope": "variable.other.php, variable.other.normal",
        "settings": {
            "fontStyle": "",
            "foreground": "#6089B4"
        }
    }
    ]
},
```

Comment: Have you tried simple "variable" scope?

Comment: Yes， I've tried that, but the vars are always white. The other scopes like "functions""keywords""strings" works good.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_textmate-theme-rules

Comment: Then try to find more specific scope with this command: **Developer: Inspect TM Scopes**

Comment: Also, can you try to remove "fontStyle" properties? They can interfere with "foreground"

Comment: Hi Alex, remove "fontStyle" properties doesn't affect anything. Then I tried "Inspector TM Scopes"。It seems many different places I want to differ are all recognized as "meta.block.c", such as macros, local variables and types I defined. How does VSC detect these scopes, does it do this by plugins? Can I do anything to improve the scope identification?

Comment: "meta.block.c" is a general scope; doubt you can do something with it. Syntax highlight for C comes from [atom/language-c](https://github.com/atom/language-c) , I could be wrong tho. Don't really know how to improve TM grammar :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had the same issue. You can change the color like this:

in `settings.json`:

```json
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "not_here": "you need the semantic token colors",
    },
    "editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[the theme to modify]": {
            "enabled": true,
            "rules": {
                "macro": "#BD63C5"
            },
        },
    },
```